# Api fetching in react native - using axios

Tags: react-native, api

I am trying to fetch data from API game news.
Link of API: https://rapidapi.com/danielilieprojects-G7QdvK7X5Ao/api/videogames-news2/

I am not getting any data from the API.
It looks like API is giving me infomation in string, so I thnik mybe its problem there.
Any Ideas what is wrong with my code?

API returns this data:

```json
{
  "title": "GTA 6 release date rumours, news, and speculation",
  "date": "Fri, 03 Feb 2023 17:06:57 +0000",
  "description": "Want to know more about the GTA 6 release date? Given how many years it takes to create open worlds of the same calibre as GTA V, it’s no surprise that Rockstar Games has already spent years developing GTA 6. Like most developers, Rockstar prefers to keep its secrets close to its chest until they’re close to the end of development, so we may not see any official GTA 6 gameplay for some time. Early gameplay footage of GTA 6 recently surfaced online, along with lines of source code from the game itself. Rockstar has issued a statement on Twitter which confirms that an unauthorised third party managed to access and download information from their systems, including development footage for the open-world game. However, its statement notes that the developers don’t believe this leak should impact the development of their long-term projects or disrupt their live service games.",
  "image": "https://www.pcgamesn.com/wp-content/sites/pcgamesn/2022/02/gta-6-release-date-2022.jpg",
  "link": "https://www.pcgamesn.com/grand-theft-auto-vi/gta-6-release-date-setting-map-characters-gameplay-trailers"
}
```

Games component

```js
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, FlatList } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Article from "../components/Article";

export default function Games() {
  let [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const getArticle = () => {
    axios
      .get({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://videogames-news2.p.rapidapi.com/videogames_news/search_news",
        params: { query: "GTA" },
        headers: {
          "X-RapidAPI-Key":
            "8114fa0745msh7596481771a0acbp1eb7e4jsnaae758420c49",
          "X-RapidAPI-Host": "videogames-news2.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        setArticles(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      })
      .finally(function () {
        setLoading(true);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getArticle();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={articles}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Article
            image={item.image}
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            sourceName={item.source.name}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `articles` does not seem to contain a `source.name` for the `sourceName` you're passing to the `Article` component

Answer (score 1):

Axios returns a `data` object with the **response**. This is where the your data is stored. To make sure your data is correct you can do a `console.log`

```js
.then(function (response) {
  // console.log(response);
  setTitle(response.data[0].item.title);
  setArticle(response.data[0].item.description);
})
```

Comment: I changed my code a little, let me update you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

- You are using axios.get instead of axios.get method. The correct syntax is axios.get(url, [config]) where url is the URL to access and config is an optional configuration object.
- In your response, you are trying to access the data as response[0] but the actual data structure is unknown. You should use response.data to access the data.
- You are trying to map title and article directly from the response, but you have not assigned the response data to these state variables correctly. You need to update the state values inside the .then block, like this:

```
    .then(function (response) {
        setTitle(response.data);
        setArticle(response.data);
    }
```

Comment: So i end up fixing all isuses you wrote and i get this error: facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.string, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @AntonioKovačić  The error usually occurs when you are trying to set an object as a string, but it can only be set as a Map or similar object. To fix this, you need to make sure that you are passing the correct data type for each variable. If you are trying to pass an object as a string, you should extract the required data and then pass it as a string. For example, if you are trying to pass the description from the API response as a string, you should first extract the description from the response and then set it as a string.